# Implicit recommendation with Vowpal Wabbit - recommendations are the same for all users

Tags: machine-learning, recommendation-engine, vowpalwabbit

I have ~3000 users downloading ~100 reports, so I treat this as *implicit recommendation* problem.

The user/item matrix is filled (non-zero) for about 9% of combinations, users seemingly not reporting similar subsets of reports, numbers of downloads vary wildly.

I'm following tutorial https://getstream.io/blog/recommendations-activity-streams-vowpal-wabbit/

I have shuffled the data:

```
% head downloads.vw
2 |u jane |r 72
0 |u bob |r 57
0 |u jim |r 6
1 |u zoe |r 41
0 |u peter |r 14
0 |u sonya |r 65

% head reports.vw
|r 72
|r 65
|r 80
|r 24
|r 36
|r 78
|r 74
|r 17
|r 12
|r 25
```

I'm training `vw` like so:

```
LATENT=20

vw -d downloads.vw --rank "$LATENT" --interactions ru

gd_mf_weights -I downloads.vw --vwparams "-d downloads.vw --rank $LATENT --interactions ru"
```

Getting recommendation:

```
echo '|u jane' | recommend --topk 10 -U /dev/stdin -I reports.vw -B blacklist.vw --vwparams "-d downloads.vw --rank $LATENT --interactions ru --quiet"
```

For any rank (latent factors) between 5 and 40 I'm gettting the same recommendations for every user, e.g. for rank 20:

```
% head -n 30 recommendations_20.txt
0       |u jane|r 72
0       |u jane|r 80
0       |u jane|r 74
0       |u jane|r 25
0       |u jane|r 12
0       |u jane|r 78
0       |u jane|r 17
0       |u jane|r 36
0       |u jane|r 65
0       |u jane|r 24
0       |u peter|r 72
0       |u peter|r 80
0       |u peter|r 74
0       |u peter|r 25
0       |u peter|r 12
0       |u peter|r 78
0       |u peter|r 17
0       |u peter|r 36
0       |u peter|r 65
0       |u peter|r 24
0       |u sonya|r 72
0       |u sonya|r 80
0       |u sonya|r 74
0       |u sonya|r 25
0       |u sonya|r 12
0       |u sonya|r 78
0       |u sonya|r 17
0       |u sonya|r 36
0       |u sonya|r 65
0       |u sonya|r 24
```

Is this really justified or I'm doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

I overlooked setting interactions parameter wrong, thanks to arielf for pointing this out. However, I still get the same recommendations for every user.

Another question: Per this [article](http://blog.fastforwardlabs.com/2018/01/22/exploring-recommendation-systems.html?imm_mid=0faf23&cmp=em-data-na-na-newsltr_20180131):

> In recommendation systems, it is important to remove both users who
>   have interacted with many items and items that have many ratings.
>   Intuitively, users who like many items do not add any useful
>   information to our system, as they are not selective enough.
>   Similarly, items that many users like will tend to be overly
>   recommended.

Can this be the source of this phenomenon (the same recommendations for every user)? So far I have not removed such cases from the data.

Comment: Could you explain the `--interactions is`? Seems like your name-spaces are `u` and `r` (not `i` and `s`)

Comment: @arielf Thanks for pointing this out, I overlooked this. Please see update.

Comment: I only pointed out the 1st thing I noticed :-) I'm not very familiar with the `recommend` or  `gd_mf_weights` utilities but looking at this again, I also don't see where are you storing the model so it can be used later. Normally this is done using:  `-f model_filename` (to store the model on disk at end of learning) and `-i mode_filename` (to load it at start of a subsequent run). More tips: you may also get some more insights from passing `--verbose` or `-v` option to `recommend`. There's also a `--bf_bits` option for "number of items to recommend" (look at the source `library/recommend.cc`)